# Magento 2 Injecting Object in $data array

Tags: magento2, module, dependency-injection, di, virtualtype

I am trying to inject my custom object in constructor like this in di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Result">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="catalogFilterHelper" xsi:type="string">Package\Module\Helper\Data</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="catalogFilterHelper" xsi:type="object">Package\Module\Helper\Data</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

And trying to access it in theme template like 
`app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/advanced/result.phtml`

`$block->getData('catalogFilterHelper');`

It returns null.

When I am trying to get the object in the same template by using object manager.

```
//$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
//$block = $objectManager->get(\Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Result::class);
```

I get the proper result.

So seems like when layout is executed and blocks are created it overides the di.xml configurations for blocks $data array.

Answer (score 2):

After some debugging I found out that Argument Replacement for Blocks using `di.xml` doesn't work. If the blocks are defined in layout.

The initialization of blocks in layout override the di.xml configuration.

To get it working I used the specific layout file and injected my object in layout block instead of di.xml. Which also called viewModel

```
<referenceBlock name="search.result">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="catalogFilterBlock" xsi:type="object">Package\Module\Helper\Data</argument>
        </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

And accessed it like this in the template

```
$catalogFilterHelper = $block->getData('catalogFilterBlock');
```